# Change href in custom template

Tags: jquery, html, razor

Wonder if someone could spare a few minutes to help to me out:

In my cshtml page I have a 'hidden-template'

```
<script id="hidden-template" type="application/x-custom-template">
    <a href="#"  class="qualURL course">
        <div class="course_wrap">
            <h2>
                <span><i class="fulllevel"></i></span>
                <span class="title"></span>
            </h2>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="level"></div>
                <div class="arrow">
                    <span class="icon-arrow-right"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</script>
```

And using jSon I'm grabbing a list of elements and using the properties of each item in the list to change the value inside this template and then append each instance of the template to a container located elsewhere in the cshtml file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: qualURL,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=uft-8',
    success: function (results) {
        globalSearchResult = jQuery.parseJSON(results); //this calls a controller and returns a list of items
        ListResultsAndFilter();
    },
    error: function (badResults) {
        alert("An error has occurred");
    }
});


function ListResultsAndFilter() {
//clear out prior to fresh loading
$('.results').html("");

//loop through and load into containing div
$.each(globalSearchResult, function (i, item) {
    var qualItem = item;
    //add filtration here
    var result = true;
    //above added for initial loading/testing
    var item = $(template).clone();

    if (result) {

        //build the URL 
        var zPath = qualItem.qualificationName;
        zPath = zPath.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');
        zPath = replaceAll(zPath, '   ', '-');
        zPath = replaceAll(zPath, ' ', '-');
        zPath = replaceAll(zPath, '--', '-');

        $(item).find('.title').html(qualItem.qualificationName);
        $(item).find('.level').html(qualItem.qualificationLevel);
        $(item).find('.fulllevel').html(qualItem.discipline);
        $(item).find('.qualURL').attr('href', qualItem.qualificationName);


        //append this qualification to the results container
        $('.results').append(item);

    }

});
};
```

As you can see for each item in the list I'm cloning the template and changing the values of the HTML by finding the element by the class name and everything works as expected apart from the fact that I can't change the href value of the anchor link (class name qualURL) I'm getting no console errors but the href remains as #.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
C

Comment: Could it be that you need to look for `.qualURL .course` since you have two classes on that template?

Comment: Sadly not, I'd already tried removing one of the class names but still it won't change the link

Comment: Is `$(template)` that `.qualURL` anchor? if so, just remove the `.find()` for the `href` change.... Like this `$(item).attr('href', qualItem.qualificationName);`

Comment: GENIUS! You my friend are a GENIUS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template seems to be that `.qualURL` anchor...

So, just remove the `.find('.qualURL')` for the `href` change, since that looks for a `.qualURL` in the childrens of your template.

```
$(item).attr('href', qualItem.qualificationName);
```

Comment: Bang on. Thanking you :)

Comment: ;) I'm always happy to help.